# pygame installation not working

Tags: python, installation

Im trying to download Pygame onto my PC. When I type in Python in cmd this pops up

```
Python 3.6.2rc1 (heads/3.6:268e1fb, Jun 17 2017, 19:01:44) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

This is the version of python. Python36.
I configured a python interpreter for Pycharm so I can run basic python code.
The python intercepter is in my C:\Python36 
I want to add Python to my environment variables and the first step is to locate
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32 . In this folder it is empty. This is the third time installing and reinstalling python and to this day it still has not worked.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what's not working... it sounds like you're able to get Python to run from the command line, but you're not able to get it to work in PyCharm?  Is that the issue?  And where does pygame come in to the picture?

Comment: If you can run `python` in the command prompt, then it's already in the `PATH` environment variable, and it seems like you already know it's installed in "C:\Python36". Anyway, to see where `python` is found, run `where python` in a command prompt.

Comment: I can get python to work in pycharm but I cannot get pygame to work. To install pygame you need to use "pip" command but when I type in pip install wheel to install pygame it says pip is not recognised as an external or internal command, I thought this may be due to the fact that python is not implemented into my system variable properly thanks for verifying that. Do you know why pip is not recognised or generally why I cant install pygame @CodyPiersall

Comment: @GuyNaeem Try doing `python -m pip install [whatever]` instead of `pip install [whatever]`.  To check if a program is on your path in Windows.  pip is not in the same directory as Python, and the directory it is in probably isn't on your path.

Comment: when I do python -m pip install pygame it says You must give at least one requirement to install( see pip help install ) @CodyPiersall

Comment: Also I have pygame-1.9.3-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl in my downloads. Am i supposed to put it elsewhere?

Comment: Just typing `python -m pip install pygame` should do what you need.  If you want to install directly from the wheel you downloaded, `python -m pip install "X:\path\to\your\downloads\pygame-1.9.3-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl"` should do it.

Comment: Are you sure you initially typed `python -m pip install pygame` and not just `python -m pip install`?  The error message you were getting is the message you get whenever you don't actually tell pip to install anything.

Comment: Oh it successfully installed pygame in the command prompt but now when I go into pycharm and run a pygame application it says no module named pygame what step shall I take from now @CodyPiersall